# Define list of objects. Get by specific field in object

Tags: c#, oop

How can we create a list of objects in C# and acces them by a specific field inside this object?

For example take this object:

```
class Section
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public long Size { get; }

    public Section(string name, long size)
    {
        Name = name;
        Size = size;
    }
}
```

I would like to create a list of these objects which I can access by Section.Name.

I can create a dictionary like:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Section> validSections = new Dictionary<string, Section>
    {
        { "section-a", new Section("section-a", 1) },
        { "section-b", new Section("section-b", 2) },
        { "section-c", new Section("section-c", 3) },
        { "section-d", new Section("section-d", 4) },
    };
```

But as you see, I have to declare the section name twice, which looks inelegant. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Why not just use linq and select where(s=>s.Name==name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But as you see, I have to declare the section name twice, which looks
>   inelegant. Is there a more elegant way?

To avoid repetitve typing you can create dictionary from collection of sections via `ToDictionary` call:

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Section> validSections = new[] {
        new Section("section-a", 1),
        new Section("section-b", 2),
        new Section("section-c", 3),
        new Section("section-d", 4)
    }.ToDictionary(s => s.Name);
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If this is not *time critical* then you can use `List<Section> list = new ArrayList<Section>();` and store data in it.
 Later you can use `LINQ` to query based on name `.where(x=>x.Name=="somename")`

Answer (score 1):

First of all your Model class can look like:

```
class Section
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need the `Name` twice so you can just create a list:

```
private static List<Section> myList = new List<Section>();
myList.add(new Section {Name = "section-a", Size = 1});
// do this for all the sections ...
```

Then as other answers suggest you can use LINQ:

```
myList.Single(s => s.Name == "section-a");
```

Will simply return the **single** element where the name is "section-a".

Read more about LINQ here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that takes a list of sections and returns the corresponding dictionary. Something like:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Section> SectionDictionary(List<Section> sections) {
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Section>();
    foreach (var section in sections)
        dict.Add(section.Name, section);
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the elements using LINQ:

```
var list = ...;
var el = list.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name = nameValue);
```

Or you can create a (collection) class that implements your own indexer / getter logic. E.g. (pseudocode)

```
public class MyCollection : Collection<Section>
{
    public Section this[string nameValue]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == nameValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the usage is:

```
var coll = new MyCollection() ....;
var el = coll["Some name"];
```